# Fucntion parameter values to replace the integer from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a function the parameter has more than one values which I'm passing them after a loop. I want to use the values Im getting to replace integers in a string by there older. This is my code below

```
onGetValues: function(response) {
            var message = response;
            var myValues = [];
            //Then Im looping it here to get all the value passed from the response ie "my name", "surname", "age"
            for (var i = 0;  i < message.length; i++) {
                myValues += message[i];
            }
            //global object with a string value like 12==12AND03==Im thirty
            var test == originalGlobalString
            //how can loop in the string above to replace the integers in the string with the values from  from the respnse parameter values and display like my name == surname AND age == im thirty?
            },
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a little ambiguous. Please clarify what is not working exactly and provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm stack in getting the parameter values to loop into the original string to replace the integers with the values I get from that fucntion

Comment: Are you trying to mke a new String or a new Array? I would expect to see `myValues.push(message[i]);` the way you have it. otherwise, I would create it like so: `var myValues = "";` and then you can use the `+=` operator to append more string data. Or you can use `.join()` too. Like: `var myValues = message.join("");` So hard to help if you're not clear about what you want to do.

Comment: I want to create a new array then loop that array again against  var test = "12==12AND03==Im thirty";  to replace the integers with the array values. Is it possible?

Comment: It sounds like you want to compare a word like, thirty, to an integer. Can you provide a sample response?

Comment: A sample response could have more than one value ie "My Name" "Surname" "Age" and could be more. What I want to achieve is to replace the integers in a string with the response values. I would like to have a final string like My name==SurnameANDAge==Im thirty.

Comment: @Twisty, is the sample clear?

Comment: No, none of this is very clear at all. Please be more clear.

Comment: Okay, on that function above I can get more than one parameter argument/values, thats why I'm looping to get all the values for (var i = 0;  i < message.length; i++) {
                myValues.push(message[i]);
            }, Then I have another string var test = "12==12AND03==Im thirty"; I would like to replace the integers in the string with the values im getting from the response for example I would like to have final string of "my name ==surnameANDage==Im thirty", my name being the first response value, surname second age third

Comment: Posted an answer that I think will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have put forward is not making sense to me, but here is part of what you are asking for:

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/bo6s1e9r/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var myData = [
    "My Name", "Surname", "Age", "I'm thirty"
  ];

  function pad(i) {
    if (i.toString().length < 2) {
      return "0" + i;
    } else {
      return i;
    }
  }

  function getValues(t) {
    var myValues = [];
    var myString = "";
    $.ajax({
      url: "/echo/json/",
      type: "post",
      data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(myData)
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $.each(response, function(i, v) {
          myValues.push(v);
          myString += pad(i) + "==" + v + "AND";
        });
        //Remove last "AND"
        myString = myString.slice(0, -3);
        console.log("Array: ", myValues);
        console.log("String: ", myString);
        if (t == "array") {
          $("#results").html(myValues.join(", "));
        } else {
          $("#results").html(myString);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  $("#btn-1").click(function(e) {
    console.log("Click Event fired.");
    getValues();
  });
});
```

Now if you want to get a string that says:

```
My Name==SurnameANDAge==I'm thirty
```

You can step past one of your steps and do something like:

```
function getValues(t) {
    var myString = "";
    $.ajax({
      url: "/echo/json/",
      type: "post",
      data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(myData)
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i += 2) {
          myString += response[i] + "==" + response[i + 1] + "AND";
        }
        console.log(myString);
        $("#results").html(myString.slice(0, -3));
      }
    });
  }
```

Since you didn't really clarify what you're doing with this, it's hard to help further.

**Update**

It took a bit of head scratching, but then I realized what you were trying to do. Basically we want to template, so seek in the string for a Integer and replace it with a corresponding string, based on that index in an array.

For example, if you have this string:

```
"0==1AND2==I'm thirty"
```

and you have this array:

```
["My Name", "Surname", "Age"]
```

The result would be a new string:

```
"My Name==SurnameANDAge==I'm thirty"
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/bo6s1e9r/5/

```
  function getValues(response) {
    var partsA = testString.split("AND");
    console.log("A:", partsA);
    var partsB = [];
    var newString = "";
    $.each(partsA, function(k, v) {
      partsB = v.split("==");
      console.log("B-1:", partsB);
      if (!isNaN(partsB[0])) {
        partsB[0] = myData[parseInt(partsB[0])];
      }
      if (!isNaN(partsB[1])) {
        partsB[1] = myData[parseInt(partsB[1])];
      }
      console.log("B-2:", partsB);
      partsA[k] = partsB.join("==");
    });
    newString = partsA.join("AND");
    console.log("S:", newString);
    return newString;
  }
```

This chunks the string into pieces based on "AND". We then break those into chunks based on "==". We examine each part, using `isNaN()` (Is Not a Number function), and if we find a number, we substitute the number with the string value from our data array.

For the test data, our console will show:

```
A: Array [ "0==1", "2==Im thirty" ]
B-1: Array [ "0", "1" ]
B-2: Array [ "My Name", "Surname" ]
B-1: Array [ "2", "Im thirty" ]
B-2: Array [ "Age", "Im thirty" ]
S: My Name==SurnameANDAge==I'm thirty
```

The function then return the string. This could be improved to escape things like `"` or `'` that could cause issues. Also if you have a string like:

```
"0 is Mary==1AND2==I'm Thirty"
```

This will fail and `0` will not be detected since `isNaN()` will return `true` on a string of this nature. Your result would be:

```
"0 is Mary==SurnameANDAge==I'm Thirty"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks so much your answer solved my issue I was having

Comment: sorry to bother you again. in the event that I have a string like "236==300AND189==I'm thirty", even be more how do I go about from the answer you posted cause when I have a string like above for example its gives me this results ==AND==I'm thirty it doesnt seem to replace the integer with the corresponding words. Any idea?